# Emacs packages fails install due missing deps: pkg-info and dash

Tags: emacs, clojure, emacs24

I get the following error when installing a set of packages for my emacs client (clojure-mode)

Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `pkg-info'.
Required package`dash-1.6.0' is unavailable
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/skinney/.emacs.d/init.el':

Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

How do I solve this? A google search reveals nothing :/

Comment: This was a bug in one of packages (EPL, to be precise).  It is fixed now.  Update again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @lunaryorn noted this was caused by a bug in the EPL package. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/cask/epl/issues/7) for the details.

The new version is already on MELPA. If updating does not work for you - you might have to remove EPL and reinstall EPL manually.